# visual studio 2012 cpp files not linked

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files

I have a project, called "vertexbuffertest". The project has more than 60 header files and more than 40 cpp files. Now I want to put several header files with their corresponding cpp files in a directory called "datastucts" , which is within the vertexbuffertest directory.

But by doing this, visual studio does not link the cpp files in the directory called "datastructs" and I can not compile the project.

What is the solution, to the described problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this

```
    #include"datastructs/abc.h"
```

Comment: It is working, when I use #include "../datastructs/abc.h"  But why do I need "../"  ?!???

Comment: if your "datastucts" directory is in main project directory i.e "vertexbuffertest" as you said, then it should work without "../". As I tried myself, here it is working fine.